# Error for 'tibble' package when I install the 'dplyr' package

Tags: r, dplyr, package, installation, tibble

I am trying to install the package `dplyr` which is supposed to include the package `tibble`. When I run

```
install.packages("dplyr")
```

and then run

```
library(dplyr)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>         there is no package called ‘tibble’

I have tried running

```
install.packages("tibble",dependencies = TRUE)
```

and still get the same error. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the `dplyr` package as well, and I continue to get the same results.

Comment: When you tried `install.packages("tibble")`, were there any warnings or errors, or did it compile cleanly? Does `packageVersion("tibble")` return `"2.1.1"` (or similar), or does it error? It might be necessary to restart R (sorry, the whole "reboot and retest" mantra). Another quick check: check each of `.libPaths()` and see if you have multiple installs (and therefore possibly multiple versions) of either or both of these packages.

Comment: Yeah I've tried the "reboot"/"Restart" a few times as well.

packageVersion(tibble)
Error in packageDescription(pkg, lib.loc = lib.loc, fields = "Version") : 
  object 'tibble' not found

There was a lot of black text when 'dplyr' was installing. The first instance of an error /warning is: Rd warning: C:/Users/AppData/Local/Temp/1/RtmpGaWige/R.INSTALL280183727b4/tibble/man/as_tibble.Rd:84: file link 'matrix-class' in package 'methods' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic

Comment: In the future, please don't put code/errors/warnings of that length in a comment, as you can see they are difficult to understand. In this case (if I'm reading it correctly), if installing `tibble` does not work then `dplyr` is a moot-point: the reliance is strict and unavoidable. That "first instance" is just a warning, very common, and gives no indication of (serious) problems. I suggest this question should (for now) be completely about installing `tibble`, not `dplyr`. Without more info on `tibble`'s installation, I don't think we can be of any help.

Comment: From what I understand tibble should be one of the packages that is installed when running the installation for dplyr. In other words installing dplyr should also install tibble at the same time as it is included. I have also tried installing just tibble and get the same kinds of warnings and errors saying that it is not found. However, looking at the R package documentation on their website, it is clearly there.

Comment: `tibble` is required, correct. You mention errors when installing, but all I've seen is one warning. Please add the code and output from `install.packages("tibble")` into your question (in a code-block).

Comment: basically it is a long piece of code that says it is installing the package into a folder as "(as 'lib' us unspecified)". Then is says there is a binary version available but the source version is later: binary source needs_compilations and then it come up with a popup box asking 'Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilations?' - I have selected yes and then it outputs a lot more black text and warnings.

Comment: I don't know how to be clearer here: *"lot more black text"* is what is needed. There may very well be something important in there that you have not recognized. I know it's a lot of text, and most of it is not needed. But if you already knew which is needed and which is not, then you would not be asking. I don't *know* that the answer is in there, but most installation problems are resolvable somewhere in that morass of text. I'm not trying to be rude about this, it's just a cold fact that I do not know enough at the moment to help.

Comment: okay, how do you add a code block. This is my first time on the site and am not sure how to add it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. You can also see one way that I code-block'ed the code in your question, by editing it and seeing the underlying markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from GitHub via

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tibble")
```